# NetfilterQueue not working in a docker container

Tags: python, docker, network-programming, iptables, netfilter

NetfilterQueue is showing a weird problem when importing in a python script running in a container:

```
File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from netfilterqueue import NetfilterQueue
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/netfilterqueue.so: undefined symbol: nfq_set_verdict2
```

In the container, I have installed:

```
FROM debian:wheezy
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    bridge-utils \
    net-tools \
    iptables \
    python \ 
    scapy \
    tcpdump \
    python-nfqueue \
    build-essential \
    python-dev \
    libnetfilter-queue-dev \
    python-pip

RUN pip install netfilterqueue

COPY ./main.py /main.py

ENTRYPOINT  sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1 && ip6tables -A FORWARD -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 1 && python main.py
```

Build is working like a charm. Any idea what could cause this error on runtime?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

FYI I was able to fix this by using ubuntu as the base instead of debian. The container host is also ubuntu. I started the container with --privileged and --net=host